# Datastructure of a php tourney/cup

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I have started writing a cup tree and this works now.

I now want to ask what is a good database structure for a tourney.

I thought this way:

```
table participant
--------------
id of player
id of cup


table round
-----------
id of cup
id of player
number round


table cup matches
-----------------
id match
id of cup
id of playerA
id of playerB
number resultA
number resultB
```

Is this a good design?

Workflow:

First round: all particpants joined. Matches for round one are generated.

PlayerA enters result (he won). PlayerB accepts. Becuase match is accepted a entry is made in round. PlayerA is now in the next round.

After the last match is entered the next matches are generated.

Better ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the round number in the participant table? I see no reason for (a) storing this attribute in a separate table or (b) storing an entry for every round a player participates in. The maximum reached round per player should be enough.

Also, depending on your application, you could add the round number to a match. I know it's redundant, since you can find that out by looking at the reached round number of the loser, but when having lots of requests for this information, the extra query should be spared!?